# How to Verify that a UART is Enabled on a Beaglebone Black

Tags: debian, serial-port, beagleboneblack, uart

### Question

Is the existence of a `/dev/ttyO*` symlink evidence that the corresponding UART device is enabled? If not, how can I check whether or not the UART has been successfully enabled?

### Details

I'm learning how to use a Beaglebone Black. I'm running the Debian 9 IOT distro on a Beaglebone kernel 4.9. I'm interested in configuring the UART ports to read data from other devices. Many references seem to use the following command to check whether or not one or another UART device has been enabled:

```
ls -l /dev/ttyO*
```

It seems to me that the implicit statement here is that the existence of a `ttyO*` symlink is an indication that the corresponding UART device has been enabled, e.g. if the symlink `/dev/ttyO2 -> ttyS2` exists then this means that UART2 has been enabled. Is this correct?